# Rotated custom tile set in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, openlayers-2

I'm thinking of using Openlayers for an interactive map of a building. I'll have custom tile layers for each floor of the building's interior overlaying regular world map tiles.

The building is on a bit of an angle, though, with respect to north, and the client wants it to be displayed with the walls vertical and horizontal. This means rotating north to be 10 degrees or so from the vertical. This is what ruled out the Google Maps API.

I know Openlayers can rotate a map (example at http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.0/examples/rotation.html) but when rotated the tiles don't look so good since they no longer match the screen pixels 1:1.

For that reason, and also for ease of drawing, it'd be good if I could make the map tiles already rotated (horizontal and vertical walls) and then somehow make Openlayers aware of this.

Then when the rotation of the map is introduced the tiles would be in their native orientation once again.

Is this possible with Openlayers? How would it be done? Or must I make the tiles with north being up?

The alternative would be to abandon real world coordinates and orientation completely, which would reintroduce Google Maps as a possible technology.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the map where the rotated image shows some issues?

Comment: Do you mean the degraded visual quality I mentioned when imagery is rotated? The link to the OL3 example shows that. Click the "north" button to rotate north to "up": now the tile pixels are 1:1 with screen pixels; lines and text are crisp. But rotate it again and the pixels don't line up and you see blurring where the software has run interpolation/smoothing algorithms. It's most visible if you rotate just a degree or two. My map will always have north on an angle, and it won't be acceptable to always have that blurring visible.